# Android WebView scales about 3.5x lower resolution than the screen

Tags: android, webview

I have a fullscreen webview that loads a much smaller resolution than the screen. On the emulator its 412x684 which is about 3.5 times smaller than the screen resolution of 1440x2392. Under the dev tools -> configuration it shows density at 3.5 so im thinking that must have something to do with it but the app seems like its running at full resolution other than the webview.

I have tried stripping everything I can to minimize anything causing this and nothing seems to help.

I narrowed it down to just the webview content by showing the getMeasuredWidth/Height function like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "width "+Integer.toString(mWebView.getMeasuredWidth())+" height "+Integer.toString(mWebView.getMeasuredHeight()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is the relevant webview code

```
        rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        //relativeLayout.setFillViewport(true);
//        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);


        mWebView = new WebView(this);
          mWebView.setScrollContainer(false);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(100);
        mWebView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        relativeLayout.addView(mWebView);

        //enable remote debugging
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

           WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
           webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
         webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
           webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
               webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
           }

  webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

For good measure in the html side I have this and it doesnt make a difference with or without it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"  />
```

Im testing the resolution in the html with this (First I noticed the pictures were blurry)

```
document.body.innerHTML=window.innerWidth+"x"+window.innerHeight;
```

I dont have anything about the webview in the styles or manifest

How can I get the webview resolution to match the screen resolution?

Comment: Whats weird is that with no viewport at all completely removed from the html side it gets
981x1627
about 1.5x smaller. For some reason setting webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false); didnt make a difference

Comment: To eliminate any external factors the testing html and images are loaded locally
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
Its at a better resolution without the viewport tag but its still not native and this maybe ok but I still would like control over what it does myself rather than hoping for the best and pixel perfect would still be desired I will worry about performance concerns myself (sorry just ranting to android)

Answer (score 0):

Think a feature of android to save memory, is encoding them image a possibility, then decoding in android? bypassing any processing by the webview.

Also some service providers will compress images in transit. Make sure that's not the case.

Comment: Its not just the image though I can get the size with javascript
document.body.innerHTML=window.innerWidth+"x"+window.innerHeight;
that shows 412x684 of a native resolution 1440x2392
Also if I open the same page in chrome browser it works just fine full resolution

Comment: Actually I was wrong the chrome browser shows 941x1437 so thats still 1.5x smaller resolution than native but much better. How can I control this in my app so I have expected results?

Comment: Sorry dude i have no idea, i had this issue twice before, once was because AMP was running and the other was my service provider.   This part at the end  webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);   that will render the page again by the looks of it, so remove that see if it helps.

Comment: best remove regardless , This field was deprecated in API level 12.
This algorithm is now obsolete.

Comment: Thanks yea I have tried it with and without all those settings in as many combinations as I can with no luck I did remove it from my application because it didn't do anything. The html file and images is local in the android_assets so it shouldn't have anything effecting them from the outside.  This just seems odd that it cant be pixel perfect when google literally has an article pixel perfect ui in the webview https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

Answer (score 0):

Use the following setting:

```
webView.settings.apply {
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                domStorageEnabled = true
                useWideViewPort = true
                mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
                loadWithOverviewMode = true
            }
            webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
            webView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true
```

Comment: Those settings were already applied so this wouldn't make a difference. Im not even sure this is an issue anymore I have moved on since this was 4 years ago. I would check if you actually want to have a go at looking into it. Just let me know.